# Hook for bulk node modifications

Tags: database

I'm trying to unpublish nodes where a field = 'Closed'. This field can change so I need to run this bulk operation automatically. I've tried these hooks:

- hook_update_N
- hook_flush_caches
- hook_cron

The only hook I've had success with is a view hook (hook_view_pre_render) and sure enough my bulk operation worked. Here's my code for the operation:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'custom_type')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_status', 'value', array( 'Closed' ), '=' );

$result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);


 foreach ($nids as $nid) {
    $node = node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE);
    // do something awesome
    $node->status = 0;
    node_save($node);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you place the code depends on when you want it to run. Usually these things goes best in `hook_cron()`, but cron needs to be set up to run for that to work.

Instead of doing bulk update you might want to consider changing the published value in [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) instead, i.e. when saving the node. Example (untested):

```
function mymodule_node_presave() {
  $w = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node->original);
  $var = $w->field_status->value();
  if ($var == 'Closed') {
    $w->status = 0;
    $w->save();
  }
}
```

Concerning your code otherwise it should work afaik, but it would be better to load all nodes at ones. Something like this:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $w = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
  $w->status = 0;
  $w->save();
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Yeah, but that would be I would have to go and save each post. The field will be dynamically set using some feed importer. Is there some other hook? I don't want to wait until the node is saved.

Comment: If you add the presave hook you can run your other script once in a PHP enabled node or in Devel's "Execute PHP code" field to update old posts.